# Boundary of a convex body

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I need your help in defining a boundary for a given convex body, $P$ without knowing the shape of $P$ meaning that I can't say that $P$ is a polygon or any shape which is convex.

Meaning that by using the properties of a convex body I need to define a function or a subset of points which are on the boundary of $P$.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be any topological space, and $A$ be a subset of $X$. A point $p \in A$ is a boundary point if every neighborhood of $p$ contains points on the interior of $A$ and points in the complement of $A$.

This notion is more general, as it does not require $A$ to be convex, or to even be a space with a notion of convexity involved. Since your set has a shape, it probably lives in some nice metric space like $\mathbb R^2$ or something, and so this notion should be really intuitive and geometric.

Comment: Is there a "representation" of the boundary points of P which relies on the convexity of P ?

Comment: Not to my immediate recollection, but I've never studied anything specialized to convex bodies.

Comment: thanks for the help.
If any one  else knows please do share.

Answer (score 1):

You can think about the support function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function .
This function could describe the tangent half-hyperplanes in each point of the boundary. A good reference for this is the book "Geometry Tomography"